# What would the equivalent statement be in MySQL 5.6.39?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I recently moved to a shared host that has MySQL 5.6.39 instead of MariaDB 10.x, I was wondering what would the equivalent of the following MariaDB statement in MySQL?

```
SELECT rank,
       total
FROM
  (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                             ORDER BY `prestige` DESC, `xp` DESC) AS rank,

     (SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM Modular_LS) AS total,
                            steamid
   FROM Modular_LS) sub
WHERE sub.steamid = '%s'
```

I got as far as this, but now I'm stuck

```
SELECT rank, total FROM
                        (SELECT @rank := @rank +1 as rank FROM Modular_LS,
                        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Modular_LS) AS total, steamid FROM Modular_LS) sub,
                        (SELECT @rank := 0) r ORDER BY `prestige` DESC, `xp` DESC) t;
```

The table structure contains the column steamid, xp, prestige

My goal is to order by prestige descending first and then xp descending to put it in a ranking like-order, then using WHERE query to find a specific player's ranking. The output of which contains the rank (position) and the total (total amount of records)

Comment: MySQL 8.0 has the "windowing" functions such as `ROW_NUMBER()` and `OVER`.  (OK, that was not your question.)

Comment: Explain, in English, what you are trying to get from the query.  If practical, provide a small test case with input and desired output.

Comment: @RickJames Added to the post

Comment: The player with the highest `prestige` is `rank` 1?  And the query needs to compute the rank?

Comment: The player with the highest prestige and xp, it's order descended by both column, and yes it needs to compute the rank (row number)

Comment: `select ... from ...`, not `select ... from ..., ... from ...`. Apart from that, the idea of your code is already the equivalent of your original code and should give you the same ranks, otherwise please post the result you get and the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours, this is what I came up with that solved my problem.

```
SELECT
        sub.rank
        ,sub.total
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                    t.id
                    ,t.steamid
                    ,@rownum : = @rownum + 1 AS rank
                    ,(
                        SELECT
                                COUNT (*)
                            FROM
                                Modular_LS
                    ) AS total
                FROM
                    Modular_LS t JOIN (
                        SELECT
                                @rownum : = 0
                    ) r
                ORDER BY
                    t.prestige DESC
                    ,t.xp DESC
        ) sub
    WHERE
        sub.steamid = '%s'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will get you started:

```
SELECT  @rank := IF(player_id = @prev, @rank + 1, 1), @prev := player_id
    FROM ( SELECT  @rank := 1, @prev = 0 ) AS init
    JOIN ( SELECT  player_id
               FROM  Modular_LS
               ORDER BY  prestige DESC, SP DESC 
         ) AS x ;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is exactly how far I got in my original attempt SQL statement